# adding page breaks in a table while printing

Tags: javascript, css, printing

Here is a rough structure of my php page -

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th> header 1 </th>
    <th> header 2 </th>
  </tr>

 foreach (values as value) {

  <tr>
    <td> column 1 </td>
    <td> column 1 </td>
  </tr>

/* Here if condition is true and media=print I want to close the table, add a page break and start a whole new table as below so the page prints nicely */

  if (condition) {
     </table>
     <div style='page-break-after:always;'> </div>
     <table>

     <tr>
       <th> header 1 </th>
       <th> header 2 </th>
     </tr>

 }

}
```

Is there a way (maybe in javascript) to check if media=print and then add page breaks in a table?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CSS style guide for your printing needs. Add a class `page-break` to where you need the page break.

```
@media all {
  .page-break  { display: none; }
}

@media print {
  .page-break  { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

> The first declaration ensures that the page-break is never seen
>   visually...while the second ensures that the page break is seen by the
>   printer.

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```